# Keypress events in Dojo's on module

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have started using Dojo's new [on module](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on) to add my events. It works fine, but now I've run into a problem. When using `keypress` event I can't seem to get the character value (for example "2" or "b") from the pressed key. Previously I've used the `behavior`module, and the `connect` module, and then I have been able to get it by using `e.keyChar` or `e.charOrCode`, but now they´re *undefined*.

I have an event set up like this:

```
on(element, 'keypress', function(e)
{
    console.log(e.keyCode); //works, but not what I need
    console.log(e.charOrCode); //undefined
    console.log(e.keyChar); //undefined
});
```

How do I get the character of a pressed key when using this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I think what you want is to use `e.keyCode` in conjunction with the JS-native `String.fromCharCode()` in order to get the desired character value.

```
on(element, 'keypress', function(e) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  if (character === 'a') { // do a stuff } else { // do something else }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Do you know why I can't use the `e.keyChar` for example, anymore? the docs seem to mention it everywhere, but it's disappeared in the `on` module. Another question is, is this safe in all browsers? I like using frameworks/toolkits because they normalize behavior.

Comment: See section 3.1 on this [page](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html). You'll see that `keyCode` is the only value used by all of the browsers. Now, that said, they each have special handling for some keys. I've looked through the code which implements the `keypress' event handling in dojo and can confirm that they are trying to normalize some of these differences.